# Within a map, How can i compare the value of a pair to the key of proceeding pair?

Tags: c++, data-structures, maps

So I have this assignment that I need to read a gigantic text file that includes strings of words separated by spaces into a map. the problem is i need to compare the value of a pair to the key of the pair after and if they match I need to compare the value of the pair that I am currently at to the key of the one after it and so forth. until I form a phrase.there is only one phrase in a very big text file that meet these criteria.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main()
{

    std::string line;
    std::map <std::string, std::string> mymap;

    std::ifstream inFile("shuffled_words.txt");

    if (inFile)
    {
        std::string key = "";
        std::string value = "";

        while (getline(inFile, line, '\n'))
        {
            std::istringstream s(line);
            
            while (s >> key>> value || !s.eof()) {
                if (s.fail())
                {
                    
                    s.clear();
                    std::string key,value;
                    s >> key >> value;
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    mymap[key] = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "file could not be read" << std::endl;
    }
    inFile.close();

    for (auto itr = mymap.begin();
        itr != mymap.end(); ++itr) {
        std::string _second = itr->second;
        for (auto itr = mymap.begin();
            itr != mymap.end(); ++itr) {
            if (_second == itr->first) {

                std::cout << _second << itr->second;
            }

        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you maybe give an example of the input and how you're supposed to handle it? I'm having a hard time following your description of what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: `std::map` is a sorted container, so the order of the pairs in the map is likely to not match the order of the words in the text file. Is that what you really want?

Comment: Since your question assumes that the data was successfully read from the file, you can drop that part from the question's *example* code. Just initialize `mymap` with, say, five pre-selected key-value pairs and have a comment indicating that there is much more data read from a file in production.

Comment: I think you'd be better off using a vector of pairs rather than a map?